# How to get DataSet.ReadXml to parse a DateTime attribute as a typed DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, datetime, dataset

I have an XML string which contains Dates formatted "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss".

I'm loading this XML into a dataset using `DataSet.ReadXml()`.

How can I ensure that this Date is stored in the DataSet as a typed DateTime so that I can Sort, Format and RowFilter on it accordingly.

My test harness is as below:

ASPX Page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="XmlDateTypeList.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test.XmlDateTypeList" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dddd dd MMMM yyyy}" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class XmlDateTypeList : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(
                new XElement("List",
                    new XElement("Item",
                        new XAttribute("Name", "A"),
                        new XAttribute("Date", "21/01/2010 00:00:00")
                    ),
                    new XElement("Item",
                        new XAttribute("Name", "B"),
                        new XAttribute("Date", "12/01/2010 00:00:00")
                    ),
                    new XElement("Item",
                        new XAttribute("Name", "C"),
                        new XAttribute("Date", "10/01/2010 00:00:00")
                    ),
                    new XElement("Item",
                        new XAttribute("Name", "D"),
                        new XAttribute("Date", "28/01/2010 00:00:00")
                    )
                )
            );

            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataSet.ReadXml(new StringReader(xDoc.ToString()));

            GridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is painful but the root issue is that your xml data can't be strongly typed in this case because the date format is not in the `xs:date` format and you can't change the type once the data is in the data set. Further complicating things is that .NET wont auto format "28/01/2010 00:00:00" as a date. So, just a copy from one data table to another with the correct data type and reformatting the date string along the way. This code works, but is far from elegant. Good Luck.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Xml.Linq;
    using System.Data;
    using System.IO;

    public partial class xmltest : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(
                new XElement("List",
                    new XElement("Item",
                        new XAttribute("Name", "A"),
                        new XAttribute("Date", "21/01/2010 00:00:00")
                    ),
                    new XElement("Item",
                        new XAttribute("Name", "B"),
                        new XAttribute("Date", "12/01/2010 00:00:00")
                    ),
                    new XElement("Item",
                        new XAttribute("Name", "C"),
                        new XAttribute("Date", "10/01/2010 00:00:00")
                    ),
                    new XElement("Item",
                        new XAttribute("Name", "D"),
                        new XAttribute("Date", "28/01/2010 12:33:22")
                    )
                )
            );

            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataSet.ReadXml(new StringReader(xDoc.ToString()));

            DataSet dataSet2 = dataSet.Clone();

            dataSet2.Tables[0].Columns[1].DataType = typeof(DateTime);

            // painful, painful copy over code from dataset1 to dataset2 
            foreach (DataRow r in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
            {

                DataRow newRow = dataSet2.Tables[0].NewRow();
                newRow["name"] = r["name"];

                newRow["Date"] = DateTime.ParseExact(r["Date"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

                dataSet2.Tables[0].Rows.Add(newRow);

            }

            GridView1.DataSource = dataSet2.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean that XML can't be strongly typed? The problem is that your XML data does not contain a valid date. There is precisely one representation of dates in XML, and that isn't it. Look up the `xs:Date` format in XML Schema if you're interested in having your strings be considered dates by tools that expect XML to follow XML standards.

Comment: Ok right, I will update my answer, you can type xml dates but not in the example because the date is in an odd format. It is a valid date (this is standard in the UK) just not a valid date per XML schema.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped. In the end I actually converted the date into the correct format using string manipulation in an xslt and then loaded an xsd in order to tell the dataset that it was a date.