# How to move DateTime to and from XML and Dataset

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

How can I make sure that when I write a DateTime value to an xml file from a dataset with dataset.WriteXml,
I can subsequently retrieve a DateTime into a new dataset using dataset.ReadXml.
At the moment I appear to get a String holding the date and time.

Any thoughts
Richard

Comment: Try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229077/how-to-get-dataset-readxml-to-parse-a-datetime-attribute-as-a-typed-datetime

Comment: Just parse the string as a DateTime...its not hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write the XML, use the overloaded function with XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema. That should preserve your types when you serialize and deserialize.

```
DataSet1.WriteXml(fileName, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```