# FormatException on Reading XML into DataTable

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, datatable, culture

I'm using the function datatable.ReadXml(TextReader) to convert an XML into a Datatable with the following code:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable("Document");
... (Add the Columns to the Table)
TextReader textReader = new StringReader(xmlString);
table.ReadXml(textReader);
```

The xml is generated from an other Server. (DMS)

This works Fine on almost every machine.
But on one windows 8.1 computer that expression throws the following error:

```
System.FormatException: Die Eingabezeichenfolge hat das falsche Format.
   bei System.Number.ParseSingle(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   bei System.Single.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider)
   bei System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToSingle(String s)
   bei System.Data.Common.SingleStorage.ConvertXmlToObject(String s)
   bei System.Data.XmlDataLoader.LoadColumn(DataColumn column, Object[] foundColumns)
   bei System.Data.XmlDataLoader.LoadTable(DataTable table, Boolean isNested)
   bei System.Data.XmlDataLoader.LoadData(XmlReader reader)
   bei System.Data.DataTable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader, Boolean denyResolving)
```

By try and error testing i found out, that the following problem ocurs: There is a Date in Format yyyy-MM-dd in one XML Node. Somehow the Method ReadXml can't parse this date on the specific machine.

The culture on both (the working and the not working) machines is:
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture: de-CH
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture: de-DE

When i change the system culture on the not working system to en-CA. It works correct.

What is the Problem?
How can I solve it?

Here an example XML:
XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<DocumentInfo>
    <DocumentList>
        <DocCount>1</DocCount>
        <FoundMore>False</FoundMore>
        <Document>
            <DocID>KG0000001</DocID>
            <DocType>01. Administration</DocType>
            <DocTypeShort>DADMI</DocTypeShort>
            <DocNumber>B_10000</DocNumber>
            <LastReleasedVersion>0</LastReleasedVersion>
            <ImportDate>2014-05-22</ImportDate>
            <DocState>Freigabe</DocState>
            <FileType>PDF</FileType>
            <FileSizeBytes>678617</FileSizeBytes>
            <FileSizeKB>662.71</FileSizeKB>
            <OriginalFilename>B_10000</OriginalFilename>
            <DocChangedAt>2014-05-22</DocChangedAt>
            <Origin/>
            <dok_dat_feld_1>39099</dok_dat_feld_1>
            <dok_dat_feld_2>11364</dok_dat_feld_2>
            <dok_dat_feld_3>Anträge</dok_dat_feld_3>
            <dok_dat_feld_4>Fragen.pdf</dok_dat_feld_4>
            <dok_dat_feld_9>männlich</dok_dat_feld_9>
            <dok_dat_feld_12>6.41.11.72</dok_dat_feld_12>
            <dok_dat_feld_13>Nein</dok_dat_feld_13>
            <dok_dat_feld_21>Jxxx</dok_dat_feld_21>
            <dok_dat_feld_50>2013-11-27</dok_dat_feld_50>
            <dok_dat_feld_51>2014-04-08</dok_dat_feld_51>
            <dok_dat_feld_54>2014-05-22</dok_dat_feld_54>
        </Document>
    </DocumentList>
</DocumentInfo>
```

Comment: How does the XML look like?

Comment: 31.25 in one culture is equivalent to 31,25 and same is with date where there is ambiguity because of culture difference, you can define culture depending on your xml and then convert it to client culture

Comment: I genuinely have no idea how to answer this question, but have just been looking at two very similar ones, both of which suggest that this page may be of interest: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Carra i Posted the xml into my question

Comment: See if this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2292600/2258

Comment: @RichardMorgan should work (not yet tried). But is realy not nice.

Comment: Don't use a text reader.  Try a StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString); table.ReadXml(reader).  The StringReader will ignore the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably fix it by doing this:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

The other solution seems to be to change the creation of the XML to use a WriteXml equivalent.

Comment: I allready tryed that. It doesn't change anything. I can't change creation of the XML. Thanks for answer.